# MySQL performance after backup and restore

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a MySQL database, 8.0.3, innodb. There is one table that contains about 500,000 records. And I have a simple sql query that gives me the result after 30 seconds of running. After backing up and restoring the database, the performance of this query improved and the sql query took about 3 seconds to complete. After a period of time, the number of records in this table increased by 100,000 records, and the same query became slow again. I repeat the restore of the backup and speed up the request again. How can you keep the speed without backup/restore?
Thank you

So,

```
'CREATE TABLE `a_store` (`f_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
`f_document` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`f_store` int DEFAULT NULL,
`f_type` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
`f_goods` int DEFAULT NULL,
`f_qty` decimal(14,4) DEFAULT NULL,
`f_price` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`f_total` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`f_base` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`f_baseDoc` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
`f_reason` int DEFAULT NULL,
`f_draft` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`f_id`),
KEY `fk_store_idx` (`f_store`),
KEY `fk_goods_idx` (`f_goods`),
KEY `fk_store_type_idx` (`f_type`),
KEY `idx_astore_base` (`f_base`), 
KEY `fk_store_document_idx` (`f_document`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_goods` FOREIGN KEY (`f_goods`) REFERENCES `c_goods` (`f_id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_store` FOREIGN KEY (`f_store`) REFERENCES `c_storages` (`f_id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_store_document` FOREIGN KEY (`f_document`) REFERENCES `a_header` (`f_id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_store_type` FOREIGN KEY (`f_type`) REFERENCES `a_type_sign` (`f_id`)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'

CREATE TABLE `a_header` (
   `f_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
   `f_userId` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_state` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_type` int DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_operator` int DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_createDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_createTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_partner` int DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_amount` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_comment` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_payment` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_paid` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`f_id`),
   KEY `idx_date` (`f_date`),
   KEY `fk_operator_idx` (`f_operator`),
   KEY `fk_state_idx` (`f_state`),
   KEY `fk_type_idx` (`f_type`),
   KEY `id_partner` (`f_partner`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_operator` FOREIGN KEY (`f_operator`) REFERENCES `s_user` (`f_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_state` FOREIGN KEY (`f_state`) REFERENCES `a_state` (`f_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_type` FOREIGN KEY (`f_type`) REFERENCES `a_type` (`f_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8



 CREATE TABLE `c_goods` (
   `f_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `f_supplier` int DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_group` int DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_unit` int DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_name` tinytext,
   `f_salePrice` decimal(12,3) DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_lastinputprice` decimal(14,3) DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_lowlevel` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_group1` int DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_group2` int DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_group3` int DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_group4` int DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_saleprice2` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_enabled` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_scancode` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_service` smallint DEFAULT '0',
   `f_description` text,
   `f_storeid` int DEFAULT NULL,
   `f_wholenumber` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`f_id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `f_scancode_UNIQUE` (`f_scancode`),
   KEY `fk_group_idx` (`f_group`),
   KEY `fk_unit_idx` (`f_unit`),
   KEY `idx_goods_enabled` (`f_enabled`),
   KEY `idx_storeid` (`f_storeid`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_group` FOREIGN KEY (`f_group`) REFERENCES `c_groups` (`f_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_unit` FOREIGN KEY (`f_unit`) REFERENCES `c_units` (`f_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9236 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And query:

```
    select g.f_id, g.f_scancode,  g.f_name as f_goodsname,
g.f_saleprice, g.f_saleprice2,                          
sum(s.f_qty*s.f_type) as f_qty, g.f_unit,          
g.f_wholenumber, g.f_storeid, g.f_lastinputprice       
from a_store s              
inner join c_goods g on g.f_storeid=s.f_goods             
inner join a_header h on h.f_id=s.f_document
where h.f_date<='2021-06-30' and s.f_store=8 and h.f_state=1 and g.f_enabled=1         
group by 1,2,3,4                  
having sum(s.f_qty*s.f_type) > 0
```

Explain:
[image]

a_store contains ~500.000 records, a_header ~300.000 and c_goods ~8000

Comment: an index seems to be missing. show us the querx, the table structure and the EXPLAIN of the query

Comment: Please upgrade to a GA version (8.0.11 or later).

Comment: To analyze the sluggishness of a query, we need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the query and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Sounds like you need a weekly OPTIMIZE of the table that is growing significantly. Provide the information requested by Rick James a few hours ago, please

Comment: Please share more details - why does the `EXPLAIN` result contain indices that are not listed in your create statements (like `fk_store_draft_store_idx`)? Have you forgot to add anything, like the definition of `a_store_draft`?

Comment: Oh! this explain of another query, I corrected question :)